# SharePoint 2010 Custom List Forms Using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Can any one guide how to create a custom form which i can use to add items to a list using Visual Studio 2010 only? without SPD neither InfoPath?

Answer (score 2):

Simple process:

- do your page using asp.net webforms
- use SharePoint Object Model to create the item in your SharePoint List : [SPListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467435.aspx)

Exemple:

```
SPWeb mySite = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPListItemCollection listItems = mySite.Lists[TextBox1.Text].Items;

SPListItem item = listItems.Add();

item["Title"] = TextBox2.Text;
item["Stock"] = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text);
item["Return Date"] = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox4.Text);
item["Employee"] = TextBox5.Text;

item.Update();
```

Comment: can you point me to a simple tutorial how to wire aspx page with the add item ? please explain more regarding wiring with sharepoint the rest inside the aspx is kinda ok for me

Comment: Create a new project of type "empty sharepoint project".  Right click on the project and "add" "new item" then find "application page" and you've now added a new application page.  If you are running VS on the Sharepoint server then right click on the project and choose "deploy", if not, choose "package" and deploy the WSP (found in bin/debug folder) to the sharepoint server you want it to be on.